# Content Security Policy CSP

Tags: security

On Craft 2.x, is it a known limitation that we must allow `unsafe-inline` for `script-src` in the Content-Security-Policy? My admin dashboard fails to load when I don't allow it.

...Trying to get a high grade on [Mozilla Observatory](https://observatory.mozilla.org/) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I implemented this recently and what I ended up doing is return the content security headers using PHP. Depending on the request path (is it a CP URL or not?), we send CSP headers with unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval or not.

Of course, the CP is still unsecured, but what you can do is to specify a custom domain for the CP in your configuration (using the "[baseCpUrl](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#baseCpUrl)" key). Something like "admin.yourwebsite.com" that only certain users can access (using IP filtering for example).

It is still not a perfect solution, but we cannot do anything at the CP level unfortunately. I hope this will not be an issue anymore in Craft 3.

Comment: Does Craft 3 avoid this issue with `unsafe-inline`?